# Windows Service Multi Core Utilisation

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services, windows-server-2003

We have an number of old visual C++ 6 windows services that are currently running on a single server. The problem seems to be that all of the service seem to utilise only a single core. (There are 4 cores)

Isn't the multi core utilisation (on windows server 2003) supposed to be optimised by the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. As long as each service is single threaded (or uses a single process) all the OS can do is to assign to each service a different core to run it in parallel to the rest of the services. The OS can't parallelize a single thread of execution.

Comment: That seems fair but all of the services seem to be assigned to the first core? (The other 3 have < 3% usage)

Comment: @Carl: Are you saying you have a single core with 100% utilization and 3 cores with 3%? What if you add a different CPU heavy process to the mix, do then the other cores start being utilized more?

Comment: It seems to hang and wait until the 1st cpu is free again. No change to the other cores

Comment: Hmmm, weird. Are you using the SP6? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A8494EDB-2E89-4676-A16A-5C5477CB9713&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeah. It seems to work fine on our test servers (which are actually 2 quads hyperthreaded) so 16 cores. Just one of those things I suppose. Will update this if I find anything :-)

Comment: @Carl: Maybe you've set CPU affinity on the production server for the services? That could explain the behavior.

Comment: Thanks Vinko. I will look into this (the server is at a customer site so will take some time to organise).